# EE2 Channel Form: How to keep value in checkbox category?

Tags: categories, safecracker, channel, checkbox

I am (again)  struggling with how to keep the value in a Channel Form when showing category as checkboxes. There are quite a few posts here but I seem not to find the answer.
Please, who can help me here with a piece of code that really works.
This is my code, this does NOT keep the value.

```
{categories show_group="5"}

    <label class="checkbox">{category_name}
    <input type="checkbox" id="{category_id}" name="{category_id}[]" value="{category_id}"{checked}>
    </label>

  {/categories}
```

Thanks, and a Happy New Year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it right.

```
<legend>Välj en grupp</legend>
      {categories group_id="5"}
        <label class="checkbox" for="{category_name}">{category_name}
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="{category_name}" value="{category_id}"{checked}>
        </label>
      {/categories}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with "keep the value" - The input type checkbox can have the attribute "checked" (resulting in a tick being displayed in the checkbox) - the value property does not set the tick.

When you run the above code of yours and look at the output - what does EE put there? Where does "{checked}" come from?

If you want to have the checkbox in checked status you will have to include some sort of IF statement:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{category_id}" name="{category_id}[]" value="{category_id}" {if condition}checked{/if} />
```

===(Updated after comment)====

If you want to allow the user to edit the Channel Entry <--> Category relation without giving them full access to the Control Panel there are two approaches:

1.) Use the Channel Form (ex SafeCracker) https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/#categories

2.) Customize the CP for your users: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin

Comment: This is the code I put in. Chennel Form. Out comes a list of categories as checkboxes. The client can tick a checkbox, but after sending the form the value is not accepted by the database. (When opening the same form=entry again for editing that checkbox is empty. (In the Control Panel everything works, but I do not want to give the client access to the CP therefore this Channel Form.

Comment: I was looking for a 'standard' solution for categories as checkboxes in stead of dropdown list, but I cannot find it anywhere. I do hope for a working solution of someone that did the same before. Many thanks!

Comment: Oh, now I think I get what you want to do: You don't want to display the categories, but also give the user the ability to check/uncheck them and by doing so link/unlink the channel entry to a category - Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Channel Form, creating a new entry or editing an existing one. Category:  in stead of the 'standard' dropdown a checkbox. The code I use to apply for field checkboxes does not work for categories and I wonder why. And I want to know if there is a possibility to use checkboxes for categories in Channel Forms.

Comment: Commenting your answer: 1) the example shows only a dropdown 2) I do not want to give users acces to the CP, all the editing for users is on the frontend ( for several reasons) . I hope you know how to code categories as checkbox  in a Channel Form? And keep the value after submit? Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you are trying to achieve - Did you look at this Q&A?

[Outputting categories as checkboxes - exp:channel:form / safecracker](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20269/outputting-categories-as-checkboxes-expchannelform-safecracker)

Comment: Yes I did, even before I asked my question here.